# wxWidgets DPI awareness (V2) not working as expected

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I want to write a small app and decided to use wxWidgets for the UI. However, when I ran [this](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.5/overview_helloworld.html) sample from the official website, I found that some of the text (specifically the menu) was blurry. I did some research and tried some things out (I'm looking for per monitor v2 DPI awareness). Here what I've tried so far:

1. I created a resource file and included wx/msw/wx.rc from it and then defined wxUSE_DPI_AWARE_MANIFEST as 2 (as described [here](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_high_dpi.html)) with no effect at all.
2. I used Windows' [SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdpiawarenesscontext) function (with DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 as argument). This fixed the primary issue but now if I start the application on a high DPI monitor and move the window to a low DPI monitor, there are graphics glitches underneath the menu entries as seen in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKpXP.png) image.
3. Combination of the two above. Again, the resource file had no effect at all and the result was always the exact same as in point 2.

As far as I can tell I followed the tutorials exactly but I can't get it to work. If you could give me **step by step instructions on how to make it work**, that would be perfect but I'd be greatful for **any hints that bring me closer to get it to work**. All the tutorials and forum threads I've looked didn't work or seemed to be incomplete (most of them just mentioned point 1 or 2 from above).

I'm on a Windows 10 machine and the wxWidgets version is 3.1.5 (latest version at time of post).

PS: I thought of using resource hacker to check whether the resource file is even included. However, in order to see anything I would have to inlcude addition resources (right?), which I wasn't able to do (Visual Studio can't read the language of the resource files that it created itself, for reasons beyond my understanding. So opening the file in anyting else than a plain text editor results in an error).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `wxUSE_DPI_AWARE_MANIFEST` but in my Visual Studio 2019 I configured the `Manifest Tool`.

In your project properties go to `Configuration Properties -> Manifest Tool -> Input and Output` and set `Additional Manifest Files` to `<wxPath>\include\wx\msw\amd64_dpi_aware.manifest` wherever your wxPath is.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with this, thanks for the hint. This had the same effect as using SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext, including the graphics glitches.

Answer (score 0):

`wxUSE_DPI_AWARE_MANIFEST` only affects `wx/msw/wx.rc`, which should be included from your own application `.rc` file and it's not clear if you do this. If you don't do it, please do.

You also should be able to open the executable in Visual Studio as resource file to check that it includes the expected manifest. If this doesn't work, there would seem to be a problem with your MSVS installation that you need to repair.

Comment: This is what I meant with point 1. Maybe my description is off but I feel like I have a serious misconseption about wxWidgets or resource files. I created a resource file called resource.rc and added #include "wx/msw/wx.rc" (made sure the path was right).
I will reinstall wxWidgets and see if that helps. Thanks for the response.

Comment: In this case you really should have a manifest in your executable. Please check that you link the `.res` file resulting from compiling your `.rc` file.